# Creating and initializing classes in C++

Tags: c++, class

I'm learning to create classes in c++ and I've created a simply Point class. It somehow doesn't compile and I have no clue what went wrong. Please help.

Point.h

```
#ifndef POINT_H
#define POINT_H

class Point {

private:
    float x, y;

public:

    //default constructor
    Point();

    //constructor
    Point(float x, float y);

    float getX();

    float getY();

    void print();
};

#endif
```

Point.cpp

```
#include "Point.h"

Point::Point(){
    x = 0.0;
    y = 0.0;
};

Point::Point(float x, float y){
    x = x;
    y = y;
}

float Point::getX(){
    return x;
}

float Point::getY(){
    return y;
}

void Point::print(){
cout << "hello" ;
{
```

main.cpp:

```
#include <Point.h>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    Point p(10.0f, 20.0f);
    p.print();
    return 0;
}
```

Below is the build message:

```
||=== Build: Debug in Point (compiler: GNU GCC Compiler) ===|
main.cpp|7|error: no matching function for call to 'Point::Point(float, float)'|
main.cpp|8|error: 'class Point' has no member named 'print'|
||=== Build failed: 2 error(s), 0 warning(s) (0 minute(s), 0 second(s)) ===|
```

Comment: Try replacing  #include <Point.h> with #include "Point.h". I presume that the Point.h file is in the same directory. You most likely have a completely unrelated Point.h header file in your system header file directory.

Comment: Please show the actual `print` code. It seems relevant. Your current listing is cut off somehow.

Comment: What's up with the open curly brace at the end of Point.cpp? Is that intentional?

Comment: Ther e is a print() there, but it's a free function:(

Comment: @Sam Varshavchik  Thanks. It works now...  my bad...

Answer (score 3):

You forgot to put `Point::` in front of `print` when defining the body.  Also, the `x = x` in the constructor won't do anything.  You need to assign to `this->x`, and likewise for y.

Comment: Thanks. It works...  For java, it is "this.x = x;". I didn't for C++, it is "this->x = x". Thanks for telling me.

Comment: I actually had to look that up... I haven't done C++ in so long and you so rarely need to mention `this` explicitly.

Answer (score 1):

always use Constructor initialize list if possible

```
Point::Point()
   : x(0.f)
   , y(0.f)
{
}

Point::Point(float x, float y)
   : x(x)
   , y(y)
{
}
```

return const for both getX() getY()

Comment: any idea why initializing with list is better than initializing with pointer?

Comment: @MLAC it's considered as best practice, it only matter if your class has user-define objects it would be faster if you were initialized them via constructor and for common type like float or int it not necessary if you care about performance.